# How to send base64 image to server - PHP

Tags: php, android, sql-server, base64

I'm sending a base64 string from an Android app to a server through a PHP file.
I got this from a tutorial video:

```
<?php
    require 'Init.php';
    header('Content-type : bitmap; charset=utf8');

    if(isset($_POST['encoded_string'])){

        $encoded_string = $_POST['encoded_string'];
        $image_name = $_POST['image_name'];

        $decoded_string = base64_decode($encoded_string);

        $path = 'ProfileIcons/' .$image_name;

        $file = fopen($path, 'wb');

        $is_written = fwrite($file, $decoded_string);
        fclose($file);
    }
?>
```

It's storing the image in the directory but when you open, it has no image. It's a blank png. Is there something wrong with the code? If so, what should I use? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the format of string returned by - $encoded_string? Check if you need to manipulate it

Comment: What tutorial did you get this from?  This is a disaster from a security perspective... pretty much anyone can write whatever they want to your server's disk.  Also, there's usually no reason to use base64... you're adding 33% overhead and wasting memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several points you should check:

1.Make sure the server has received the base64 string

> $encoded_string = $_POST['encoded_string'];

Check the length of `$encoded_string`, it should have the same length as the android client says.

2. Make sure the decoding works

   > $decoded_string = base64_decode($encoded_string);

Check the length of `$decoded_string`, it should NOT be zero or something odd.

3. Make sure the file written works

   > $is_written = fwrite($file, $decoded_string);

`$is_written` should be the length of the data that has been written to the file, if it is a `false`, then something is wrong.

Comment: Something is definily wrong. Because even if I change the code and put hard coded values manually, the image stills blank.

Comment: In where? Can you edit the question and show us what you have done?

Comment: I realized that it was working. For some reason, when I download the image it comes blank. But I don't plan to download it so it's fine. But it was nice to know the things I should check on my codes, I'm new to php. Thanks.